# Angular2 How to split string?

Tags: angular, split

Hi I am trying to split json string using possibly pipe? or I don't really know how to do it.

Right now I have json string of

"www.youtube.com||djlajdalksd.png||somethingsomething"

(These are just made up)

And I want to only get .png part.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You you can use a pipe that uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a pipe:

```js
@Pipe({ name: "splitAndGet" })
export class SplitAndGetPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string, separator: string,index:number): string {
    return input.split(separator)[index];
  }
}
```

then in template:

```
{{"www.youtube.com||djlajdalksd.png||somethingsomething"|splitAndGet:"||":1}}
```

that will return `"djlajdalksd.png"`

Comment: I'm getting `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.)` error

Comment: if I use `{{"www.youtube.com||djlajdalksd.png||somethingsomething"|splitAndGet:"||",1}}` like this I get `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ',' ` which is caused by that `,`  after saperator

Answer (score 3):

Just reference @n00dl3's answer, give an integrated version:

step1, using angular-cli to generate a pipe `ng g pipe split`

step2, modifying split.pipe.ts file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: string, sep: string, inx: number): string {
    return input.split(sep)[inx];
  }

}
```

then, in html

```
<span> {{hero.url | split:"/":4}} </span>
```