# Angular9 string to array

Tags: json, angularjs, angular, pandas

I have a pandas Series that I have converted into JSON for Angular to display in a table. The issue is that the key values are a python list under a string type. How can I convert the key into an array for Angular?

JSON:

```
{ 
"result": {
    "('', '100.83.105.90')": 1, 
    "('AS1124 Universiteit van Amsterdam', '145.18.162.122')": 2, 
    "('AS11796 Airstream Communications, LLC', '64.33.197.15')": 1, 
    "('AS16276 OVH SAS', '51.75.201.126')": 1, 
    "('AS209 CenturyLink Communications, LLC', '174.27.155.12')": 1, 
    "('AS22394 Cellco Partnership DBA Verizon Wireless', '174.241.2.88')": 1, 
    "('AS24608 Wind Tre S.p.A.', '37.227.23.201')": 1, 
    "('AS3329 Vodafone-panafon Hellenic Telecommunications Company SA', '5.55.162.202')": 1, 
    "('AS3352 Telefonica De Espana', '80.24.64.41')": 1, 
    "('AS6128 Cablevision Systems Corp.', '69.116.62.88')": 1, 
    "('AS6805 Telefonica Germany', '2.240.20.127')": 1, 
}
```

In Angular:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >{{selectedGroup}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{selectedColumn}}</th>
            <th scope="col">Hits</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits | keyvalue">
            <td>{{item.key[0]}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.key[1]}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What it looks like:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @zeterain for helping realize split/slice/etc can be applied directly to `item.key`.

Solution:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >{{selectedGroup}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{selectedColumn}}</th>
            <th scope="col">Hits</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits | keyvalue">
            <td>{{item.key | slice:1:-1 | split:", ":0}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.key | slice:1:-1 | split:", ":1}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

String splitting requires generating a custom pipe, instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205047/6575456

Slice pipe (default angular): https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to export the data from Python in a proper JSON format. You could then parse the array as a real Javascript array using `JSON.parse()`.

If you can't adjust `mvaHits`, this should parse the Python array as a Javascript array and let you access the elements in the array. Note that this wouldn't work in all cases, especially if the strings in your array had commas. I would recommend not doing these conversions in the HTML for the sake of clarity and cleanliness, but rather when you load `mvaHits` for the first time. But this should work:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >{{selectedGroup}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{selectedColumn}}</th>
            <th scope="col">Hits</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits | keyvalue">
            <td>{{item.key.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map((s) => s.slice(1,-1))[0]}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.key.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map((s) => s.slice(1,-1))[1]}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Breaking it down:

```js
item.key
    .slice(1,-1) // Removes the first and last characters in the string, removing the ()
    .split(', ') // Splits the string into an array using ', ' as the delimiter
    .map((s) => s.slice(1,-1)) // Removes the quotes from the strings in the array
    [0] // access the first element of the new array
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would like to change the JSON format to a proper one but this is the best that pandas .to_json() provides for Series..

I tried out your item slicing but got this error:

Comment: ERROR in Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 42 in [{{item.key.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map((s) => s.slice(1,-1))[0]}}] in /Volumes/proj/client/src/app/analyze/analyze.component.html@45:32 ("                       <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits | keyvalue">
                            <td>[ERROR ->]{{item.key.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map((s) => s.slice(1,-1))[0]}}</td> 
                            <"): /Volumes/proj/client/src/app/analyze/analyze.component.html@45:32

Comment: How would I do these conversions in the .ts ?

Comment: Your browser might not support this arrow function syntax. Try this instead:
`{{item.key.slice(1,-1).split(', ').map(function(s) { return s.slice(1,-1) })[0]}}`

Comment: I'm not sure how you would write this in TypeScript.

Comment: using return rather than arrow func displayed the same error  :/

Comment: I wonder if this code just isn't allowed in the handlebars in Angular. I'm not quite familiar with what Angular allows. You should be able to use this code in a similar way to convert the values in `mvaHits` when you first load the variable before it gets rendered.

Comment: turns out the way to use slice is: {{item.key | slice:1:-1}}. Also found out that split required adding a custom pipe for the angular project, documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224957/angular2-how-to-split-string. 

Thanks for your help, i'll add your work plus my discoveries to the solution :)

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you to use regular expressions in order to parse the keys. In this case is pretty simple. Regular expressions are a really powerful tool.

```
const data = { 
  "result": {
    "('', '100.83.105.90')": 1, 
    "('AS1124 Universiteit van Amsterdam', '145.18.162.122')": 2, 
    "('AS11796 Airstream Communications, LLC', '64.33.197.15')": 1, 
    "('AS16276 OVH SAS', '51.75.201.126')": 1, 
    "('AS209 CenturyLink Communications, LLC', '174.27.155.12')": 1, 
    "('AS22394 Cellco Partnership DBA Verizon Wireless', '174.241.2.88')": 1, 
    "('AS24608 Wind Tre S.p.A.', '37.227.23.201')": 1, 
    "('AS3329 Vodafone-panafon Hellenic Telecommunications Company SA', '5.55.162.202')": 1, 
    "('AS3352 Telefonica De Espana', '80.24.64.41')": 1, 
    "('AS6128 Cablevision Systems Corp.', '69.116.62.88')": 1, 
    "('AS6805 Telefonica Germany', '2.240.20.127')": 1, 
  }
};
const regex = /\('(?<asn>.*)', '(?<ip>.*)'\)/;
const mvaHits = [];
for (const key of Object.keys(data.result)) {
  const found = key.match(regex);
  if (found) {
    mvaHits.push({
      asn: found.groups.asn,
      ip: found.groups.ip,
      hits: data.result[key]
    });
  }
}
console.log(mvaHits);
```

*result*

```
[ { asn: '', ip: '100.83.105.90', hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS1124 Universiteit van Amsterdam',
    ip: '145.18.162.122',
    hits: 2 },
  { asn: 'AS11796 Airstream Communications, LLC',
    ip: '64.33.197.15',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS16276 OVH SAS', ip: '51.75.201.126', hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS209 CenturyLink Communications, LLC',
    ip: '174.27.155.12',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS22394 Cellco Partnership DBA Verizon Wireless',
    ip: '174.241.2.88',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS24608 Wind Tre S.p.A.', ip: '37.227.23.201', hits: 1 },
  { asn:
     'AS3329 Vodafone-panafon Hellenic Telecommunications Company SA',
    ip: '5.55.162.202',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS3352 Telefonica De Espana',
    ip: '80.24.64.41',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS6128 Cablevision Systems Corp.',
    ip: '69.116.62.88',
    hits: 1 },
  { asn: 'AS6805 Telefonica Germany', ip: '2.240.20.127', hits: 1 } ]
```

*html*

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >{{selectedGroup}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{selectedColumn}}</th>
            <th scope="col">Hits</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits">
            <td>{{item.asn}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.ip}}</td> 
            <td>{{item.hits}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Although you can add code logic in angular template, as an advice try not abuse of these.